# jQuery is not working using relative path

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, relative-path

I am developing a website. Everything is going fine. But now I need to add jQuery functionality to it, but it does not work using the relative path.

Here is my web directory structure:

> ROOT
>
> > application
> >
> > model
> >
> > view    <== index.php resides here.
> >
> > controller
> >
> > includes
> >
> > public
> >
> > > > css
> > > >
> > > > js <== myfile.js AND jquery.js resides here.
> > > >
> > > > images

This is how i am giving the relative path in the script tags.

> > src="../public/js/jquery.js"      <== the jquery file relative source
> >
> > src="../public/js/myfile.js"      <== the my custom file relative source

Comment: does it show a 404 in the browser console ?

Comment: Depending on what framework you're using the path is either `/js/whatever.js` or you need to use the framework's methods to get the actual path.

Comment: where is the final location of the page that is referencing data from the js folder?  If there is additional details on that page, you can always see how your page is referencing other files or images from viewing the source code and try to mimic the relative path location(s)

Comment: @karthikr it does not give any error

Comment: @Juhana i am using MVC

Comment: @blackhawk the index.php file is where i am referencing both js files and index file resides inside view folder in the Root directory. This is how i am giving the relative path. (../public/js/file.js)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use relative path. It's trouble.

The easier way to make your script always point to the right place, no matter which page you visit, is to start with a slash at the first level directory.

If 'public' is at the public html root.
Then use `src="/public/js/jquery.js"`

If the first folder is 'js'.
Then use `src="/js/jquery.js"`

Comment: It wont allow me because i have explained my complete directory structure. View and Public both directories are at same level. The js directory is inside Public directory. That is why i am writing ../public/js/myfile.js.

Comment: Not sure why you say it won't allow you. Just remove the two dots. The backpath '../' is never good to use, because the relative path depends on the folder level of your visited page. Relative path are only useful and necessary for php files, not for js or css files.

Comment: thank you so much. I removed the dots and forward slash and it worked. Actually i was using the dots to go into the external directory. Thanks for your help.

Comment: You are welcome. However by "I removed the dots and forward slash". I hope you mean you removed ONLY the dots. You must keep the first slash or else it's going to be a relative path again. In other words, src="/public/js/jquery.js" is equivalent to the absolute path src="//mydomain.com/public/js/jquery.js" except that the domain name is not necessary and extra bloat.

Comment: nicely explained. Thank you